# Got 404 error on indexing in trying to do Search Engine Friendly URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling, url-rewriting

I am trying to switch my website url to be "SEO Friendly" and i found a simple idea by php:
so move every not found page to index.php by .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

and from there i have in index.php:

```
   $url = explode('/', urldecode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

    
if (empty($url[1])){
    include "home.php";
    die();
}  else if($url[1] == "p"){
    include "s/xp.php";
    die();
} else if ( $url[1] == "d"){
    include "s/xd.php";
    die();
} else if ( $url[1] == "c"){
    include "s/xc.php";
    die();
} else {
    http_response_code(404);
    include('s/error.php');
    die();
}
```

However, the server find this as 404, so i found a solution to add:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

now the pages open it works fine, nothing wrong! but when it comes to indexing! google find the pages are 404! even if they works fine!

is there a way to let the server believes its not error? or better solution?

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
> ```

This is really a *hacky* way to implement a front-controller pattern. Apache will set a 404 HTTP response code that you then must override in your script.

Apache provides a directive just for this:

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

The behaviour is similar... any request that would ordinarily return a 404 is sent to `/index.php` except a 200 OK response code is set. You must then set the 404 response in your code (which it looks like you are doing).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource

Comment: ++ for mentioning underrated but powerful directive `FallbackResource`

Answer (score 1):

i don't understand why/how, but this works:

```
<?php header("Status: 200 OK"); ?>
```

Comment: This implies PHP is behind a "proxy" (run as CGI) which manages the HTTP response. However, you shouldn't be using `ErrorDocument` for this purpose to begin with - as mentioned in my answer.